# How to download Oracle Database 11g release 2 for Mac OS

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, linux, mac-os-x

I have been trying to download Oracle Database 11g release 2 for mac os but in the given link by oracle I can only see Linux x86  and Linux x86-64. Is this ok to use this Linux file for installing oracle database in mac

Comment: I don't believe Oracle 11.2 was ever built for the Mac.  If you want to run Oracle, I believe you'd need to run it inside a virtual machine that would itself be running, presumably, either linux or Windows.

Comment: I had Oracle 10g running on a Mac. I agree with the other posts that there is no Mac version of Oracle 11g. I also used Parallels to create a Linux VM which works well, but it is not free. You can also try Virtual Box, which has a mac version and should be free. Either way make sure that you have enough memory, otherwise your Mac might kernel panic.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle 11g R2 Database Release 2 only support Windows, Linux, and Solaris. So if you want to using Oracle 11g R2 on a Mac OS you will need to using something like [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) or [VMware Fusion](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/info/slug/desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_fusion/7_0). [You can read more about installing Oracle 11g R2 on these operating system here.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/nav/portal_11.htm)